# Use either square brackets or round parentheses with \cite using the \usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

Tags: hyperref, polyglossia, biblatex-chicago

[image]

I want to use either square brackets or round parentheses with \cite using the `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` along with `\usepackage{polyglossia}`.

As when I use the `\usepackage{hyperref}`, then there is an error.

The code is like:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{hall2012teaching,
author      = "Hall, J.K.",
title       = "Teaching and Researching: Language and Culture",
series={Applied Linguistics in Action},
editor      = "Christopher N Candin and David R Hall",
booktitle   = "Applied Linguistics in Action",
publisher   = "Taylor \& Francis",
%  address     = "Oxford",
year        = 2012,
pages       = "30-36",
chapter     = 2,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{Thesis} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate16,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{polyglossia}% the document is in English
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
 \setotherlanguage{urdu}   % with some bits in Urdu
 % the following line specifies Urdu font and its location
 %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\urdufont}[Script=Arabic]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
He gives an overview on the nature of language and culture by demonstrating 
the function of language in constructing our social identities in real world 
settings~\cite[p. 30-36]{hall2012teaching}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The output should look like the image attached.

Comment: Simply use  `\parencite` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: If you are having trouble with `hyperref` I suggest you ask a **new** question about that. Please post the exact error message you get in that case. Please also which of the many `Thesis` classes on the web you used (a link to the exact version you have would be great).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `biblatex` you can generally use `\parencite` to get citations in parentheses (as mentioned by [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553118/use-either-square-brackets-or-round-parentheses-with-cite-using-the-usepackage#comment1396456_553118)). If citations in parentheses are your go-to style I strongly suggest you use `\autocite` and tell `biblatex` to produce citations in parentheses with `\autocite` if necessary (citations in parentheses in `\autocite` is already the default with `biblatex-chicago`'s author-date flavours, so you don't need to do anything else).

Note that `polyglossia` *must* be loaded before `biblatex` (or `biblatex-chicago`). In newer versions you will get an error if you load `polyglossia` after `biblatex` in older versions some things may not work as expected.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

% polyglossia must be loaded before biblatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate16,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{hall2012teaching,
  author      = {Hall, J. K.},
  title       = {Teaching and Researching: Language and Culture},
  editor      = {Christopher N. Candin and David R. Hall},
  booktitle   = {Applied Linguistics in Action},
  publisher   = {Taylor \& Francis},
  %  address  = {Oxford},
  year        = 2012,
  pages       = {30-36},
  chapter     = 2,
  series      = {Applied Linguistics in Action},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
He gives an overview on the nature of language and culture by demonstrating 
the function of language in constructing our social identities in real world 
settings~\autocite[30-36]{hall2012teaching}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> He gives an overview on the nature of language and culture by demonstrating the function of language in constructing our social identities in real world settings (Hall 2012, 30-36).

Note also that I used `article` for the example instead of `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{Thesis}`, since there are too many Thesis classes out there to know which one you used.